# jQuery works only on click

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have html form which is saving some data to mysql database. Now I want to create an edit page for that form which will return data from mysql database to form fields for editing and then update. 
In html form i have some input fields which are disabled by default until dropdown menu is set to for example 'Yes'. When the dropdown menu option is set to yes, input field gets enabled. 
I created that in jquery and it looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#lijecnickipregled').change(function(){
        if($('#lijecnickipregled').val() === 'YES')
        {
            $("#lijecnicki").prop('disabled',false);
        }
        else
        {
            $( "#lijecnicki" ).attr( "disabled", "disabled" );
        }
    });
});
```

Now when I'm creating edit page I managed to return value from database to dropdown menu and it is set to YES, but input field with ID "lijecnicki" is still disabled for editing until I choose some other option in dropdown menu and then put it back on YES.

Here is the HTML code of dropdown menu:

```
<div class="fitem" >
            <label>Liječnički pregled</label>
            <select name="Lijecnicki" id="lijecnickipregled">
                <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
                <option value="YES">YES</option>  
                <option value="NO">NO</option>  
            </select> 
        </div>
```

HTML code of input field which is being enabled when dropdown option is set to YES:

```
<div class="fitem" id="datumzadnjeglijecnickogpregleda"  >
    <label>Datum zadnjeg lijecnickog pregleda</label>
    <input name="DatumZadnjegLijecnickogPregleda" id="lijecnicki" type="text" class="lijecnicki" disabled/>
</div>
```

And here is PHP code on edit page:

```
 <div class="fitem" >
                <label>Liječnički pregled</label>
                <select name="Lijecnicki" id="lijecnickipregled">
                    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
        <?php
                    $LijecnickiPregled = array(
                        'YES',
                        'NO',
                    );

                    $lp = $s['Lijecnicki'];

                    ?>

                    <?php foreach ($LijecnickiPregled as $pregled): ?>
                        <option <?php echo $lp == $pregled ? 'selected="selected"' : '' ?> value="<?php echo $pregled ?>"><?php echo $pregled ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </select>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking the value of lijecnickipregled when it changes; you should be checking it at load time.